# How to pass text with jQuery to AJAX submit by clicking on edit link

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can write some links:

```
<p>This value is 23456. <a class="edit" href="#" custom-data="2356">Edit</a></p>
<p>This value is 123. <a class="edit" href="#" custom-data="123">Edit</a></p>
<p>This value is 99999. <a class="edit" href="#" custom-data="9999">Edit</a></p>
```

I have a target div:

```
<div id="output">place_holder</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is click the "edit" link and pass the value of "custom-data".

This does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a.edit').click(passme());  
});


function passme(){  
    var id = $(this).attr('custom-data');
    $.post("simpleformback.asp", {id: id }, function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);});
};
</script>
```

Firebug says "elem.attributes is undefined" and points to "jquery-1.4.4.js (line 1788)" which I think means I must be calling/using something wrong.

Any help very much appreciated as I am still working to understand jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the top code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a.edit').click(passme);  
});
```

Comment: I would have never figured that out.  Works.  Thank you.  And what an extremely fast response!

Comment: I'm gonna have to become a member now.

Comment: @mikeY go for it. SO is very very helpful ^_^ and remember to accept answers, that way on future q's people would love to help you out even more :-D

Answer (score 1):

You're *calling* the `passme` function and passing its return value to `click`.

Remove `()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it.  That works- it's the short version of Neal's response.  As a newbie, Neal's response was better for me, but you were right on it.

Comment: It is extremely important that you understand **why** it works.  Writing `passme` gives the function itself, without calling it.

Comment: Okay.  So it's like (passme()) says give me back whatever passme() gives you. And (passme) is more like go do whatever passme wants you to do.

Comment: `passme()` **calls** the function; `passme` **is** the function.

Answer (score 1):

do

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a.edit').click(passme);  // no ()
});
```